# git: pre-commit-hook: python + nodejs: How to configure

Tags: python, reactjs, git, pre-commit

I have project with python and reactjs.

```
Project_folder
--Django_project
--Reactjs_project
--.git
```

I want to use pre-commit hooks for git using flake8 and black for my python project.

In this case how to tell git to check pre-commit hook only for python project.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the [pre-commit configurations](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-configyaml---top-level), like `exclude`, as [seen for flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.9.0/user/using-hooks.html).

In your case:

```yaml
-   id: myProject
    exclude: ^Reactjs_project/
```

Replace '`myProject`' by the id you have used for declaring `pre-commit`.

Comment: I am completely new to `pre-commit-config.yaml` can you show the whole file in this  case (just in general)

Comment: @Santhosh the example is in https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.9.0/user/using-hooks.html, but also in the documentation: https://pre-commit.com/#2-add-a-pre-commit-configuration